# echo partially hidden (IPV4 or IPV6) ip in a table

Tags: php

I have a table where a variable in a row containing IP information is being echoed. I think there's an issue with my if statement, because if I use the following then I can get the variable to echo:

```
echo $row['log_ip'] =  substr_replace ($row['log_ip'], $ipv4replacement, stripos     ($row['log_ip'], $ipv4needle, $offset = 2));
```

My current code:

```
$ipv6needle = ':';
$ipv4needle = '.';
$ipv4replacement = '.***.***.***';
$ipv6replacement = ':****:****:****:****:****:****:****';
if (strpos($row['log_ip'], ':') !== FALSE) {
echo $row['log_ip'] =  substr_replace ($row['log_ip'], $ipv4replacement, stripos     ($row['log_ip'], $ipv4needle, $offset = 2));
else 
echo $row['log_ip'] =  substr_replace ($row['log_ip'], $ipv6replacement, stripos     ($row['log_ip'], $ipv6needle, $offset = 2)); }
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit I couldn't get the first example to format properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is full of weird assignments, I don't know what you want to achieve with them, but here's a corrected and refactored code.

```
<?php

$offset = 2;

if (strpos($row["log_ip"], ":") !== false) {
  $needle      = ".";
  $replacement = ".***.***.***";
}
else {
  $needle      = ":";
  $replacement = ":****:****:****:****:****:****:****";
}

$row["log_ip"] = substr_replace($row["log_ip"], $replacement, stripos($row["log_ip"], $needle, $offset));

echo $row["log_ip"];
```

Answer to the question in the comment:

```
<?php

function mask_ip_address($ip_address) {
  if (strpos($ip_address, ".") !== false) {
    $parts = explode(".", $ip_address);
    return $parts[0] . str_repeat(".***", 3);
  }
  $parts = explode(":", $ip_address);
  return $parts[0] . str_repeat(":****", 7);
}

function mask_ip_address_test($ip_address, $expected) {
  assert($expected === mask_ip_address($ip_address));
}

mask_ip_address_test("17.0.0.1", "17.***.***.***");
mask_ip_address_test("fe80::200:5aee:feaa:20a2", "fe80:****:****:****:****:****:****:****");
```

Comment: This is the output I'm getting: IP
July 7, 2014, 3:30pm .***.***.***
July 7, 2014, 3:28pm :****:****:****:****:****:****:**** seems like the first part of the IP is being omitted.

Comment: I really don't understand what you want to achieve, please extend your question. At least I removed the syntax error from your code, so you might be able to achieve what you want by yourself now. Also, use an IDE (e.g. [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/)) that helps you with the syntax.

Comment: I'm just trying to display the prefix of the ip address (the first group of numbers) Example -> ipv4: 17.0.0.1 = 17.*.*.* or ipv6:  fe80:200:5aee:feaa:20a2 -> fe80:****:****:****:****:****:****:****. I tried changing the offset but that didn't help.

Comment: Now I get it, see my extended answer.

Comment: hey sorry to bother you... how would i use this function to echo $row["log_ip"] like in my example?

Comment: Just call it: `echo mask_ip_address($row["log_ip"]);` Please also mark the answer as correct if it helped you or answered your question. This ensures that your question is marked as answered (and of course I get some points).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply i'll give it a try and upvote\check it as correct shortly.